# How do I share an entire C# project?

Tags: support, sharing

I am answering a question for someone on stack but I would like to share an entire test project (C#) that I created as part of the answer. Is there any recommended approach or solution for doing this? I can certainly create and use something like drop box but I'm afraid that might not be a good longer term solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try pastebin.com

Comment: Or any of its alternatives like Github Gist, ideone, etc.- http://alternativeto.net/software/pastebin/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your answer stands on its own **without** the project (so, if wherever it gets hosted goes away, the answer is still useful).

As for suggested places - why not a repository like github? This will have the added benefit of you being able to make updates and have a revision history to the test project.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Github.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried using Google code but that seemed a little difficult to get started with. Since I've used GitHub for work I'll probably go with that. I do know that there are other repositories out there such as CodePlex but I know very little about these.